# jQuery gallery hover issue

Tags: jquery, image, hover, gallery

ok so I have this jQuery and a little css to make a basic fading image gallery. I have multiple instances of this gallery type on my page but i want to make it so that the gallery only starts when you hover over it. ive tried alsorts of hover stuff but no joy.

here is my jquery:

```
$(function() {

$('.banner-item:not(:first-child)').hide();

var carousel_timer = setInterval( carousel_next, 5000 );

function carousel_next() {
    var current = $('.banner-item:visible');
    if ( current.is(':last-child') ) {
        var next = $('.banner-item:first');
    } else {
        var next = current.next();
    }
    current.stop(true, true).fadeOut(800);
    next.stop(true, true).fadeIn(800);
}

});
```

here is my css:

```
    .banner {
    width: 200px;
    height: 75px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    position: relative;
}

.banner-item {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

here is my html:

```
<ul class="banner">
    <l class="banner-item"><img src"example.jpg"></li>
    <li class="banner-item"><img src"example.jpg"></li>
    <li class="banner-item"><img src"example.jpg"></li>
    <li class="banner-item"><img src"example.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you looked into the .hover() jquery call?
http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to allow this to work on multiple instances, you need to make sure you have reference to the element the user is hovering over.

Below is an example of using `mouseover` and `mouseout` to start and stop the carousel. Each call to the `carousel_next` method essentially just queues up another.  When the user's mouse leaves the `.banner` div, it resets.

```
(function() {
    var carousel_timer = null;
    $('.banner-item:not(:first-child)').hide();

    $('.banner').on({
        'mouseover': function() {
            var e = $(this);
            carousel_next( e );
        },
        'mouseout': function() {
            clearTimeout( carousel_timer );
        }
    });

    function carousel_next( e ) {
        var current = $(e).find('.banner-item:visible');
        if ( current.is(':last-child') ) {
            var next = $(e).find('.banner-item:first');
        } else {
            var next = current.next();
        }
        current.stop(true, true).fadeOut(800);
        next.stop(true, true).fadeIn(800);
        carousel_timer = setTimeout( function(){ carousel_next(e) }, 5000 );
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works a treat! I was going about it the wrong way i think. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are placing your code on the page without any actual trigger, therefore it will just start straight away. I think what you are looking for is a trigger - which in your case is when the mouse first hovers over it.

try this:

```
function ActivateGallery() {
    $(function() {

    $('.banner-item:not(:first-child)').hide();

    var carousel_timer = setInterval( carousel_next, 5000 );

    function carousel_next() {
        var current = $('.banner-item:visible');
        if ( current.is(':last-child') ) {
            var next = $('.banner-item:first');
        } else {
            var next = current.next();
        }
        current.stop(true, true).fadeOut(800);
        next.stop(true, true).fadeIn(800);
    }

    });
}

var carouselStarted = false;
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.banner').hover(function () {
       if(carouselStarted == false)
       {
        ActivateGallery();
        carouselStarted = true;
       }
     },
     function () {
        //mouse out code if you want it.
    });
}
});
```

Hopefully this gives you an idea of what im thinking at least or sets you on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Made a slight alteration to kmfk's answer as it was "jumping" on the hover and moving over it but still hovering so i used the hover state instead and now its very smooth :)

```
$('.thumbnail-carousel').hover(
          function(){
            var e = $(this);
            carousel_next( e );
          },
          function(){
            clearTimeout( carousel_timer );
          }
      );

    function carousel_next( e ) {
        var current = $(e).find('.thumbnail-carousel-item:visible');
        if ( current.is(':last-child') ) {
            var next = $(e).find('.thumbnail-carousel-item:first');
        } else {
            var next = current.next();
        }
        carousel_timer = setTimeout( function(){ carousel_next(e) }, 3000 );
        current.stop(true, true).fadeOut(800);
        next.stop(true, true).fadeIn(800);

    }
```